# BSOD Code 16, artifacts all over the place (gtx 260)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a following, quite dated rig

- E8400 Core 2 Duo cpu
- Intel Dragontail Peak DP35DP motherboard on Intel Bearlake P35 chipset
- 4GB ram
- Geforce 260gtx
- Corsair 650W PSU
- Windows 7 64 bit

The following things has happened in the last few days. I first decided to update my Nvidia drivers to the latest version. That was 4 days ago. PC worked fine for 2 days and I was able to play few games as well without any problems. Then 2 days ago a first crash happened while playing the new XCOM game. BSOD code 16. Just the blue screen, no artifacts. PC rebooted and worked well again, I continued playing this game for another 2 hours and went to sleep. Next evening I tried to play some BF3 multiplayer (use to play on LOW settings). Approx. 10 minutes into the game red/pink-ish artifacts appeared on the screen and game quit to desktop. Restarted the game and another 3-4 minutes afterwards another crash to desktop but this time followed shortly by BSOD Code 16. From that moment I started to seeing artifacts on random startups, including Windows loading screen and the BIOS itself. Windows would still load but soon enough it would BSOD on a simple task like opening a Internet browser. Today I get tons of artifacts (little small red dashes all over the screen) on BIOS, loading screen, normal Windows mode as well as safe mode. I suspect it wouldn't be drivers but I tried removing and sweeping them entirely in the safe mode. PC would still start with artifacts all over the place but would load the normal mode, just without the driver, in the default lowest resolution. As soon as proper Nvidia drivers are installed though and PC rebooted, Windows doesn't load at all as BSOD now appears on loading screen. However, again, if I go to safe mode and remove drivers, normal mode launches fine. So obviously crash happens only on high resolution.

I opened my machine this morning and gave it a proper cleaning even though it wasn't heavily dusted. It didn't help and number of artifacts seems to increase with every PC restart. I write these words in safe mode, which works, but I have to look through all the red dots and dashes.

I don't have built in GPU chipset so I can't try removing my Geforce card nor can I borrow A GPU from anyone else. What are my options?

I was looking into getting a completely new rig around Christmas so I'm not freaking out about this. If everything points to hardware issue I may simply decide to get the new machine earlier and don't bother with fixing this one. However it would be great to learn more if this is indeed situation that has slim chances of getting sorted.

I realize BSOD Code 16 is rather popular topic online but every story seems a bit different and there can be number of issues with it. Hence a new thread.

Comment: This does sounds very suspiciously like the graphics card has died.  Artifacts in the BIOS and loading screen, before any real drivers have had a chance to start up suggests that something is fundamentally wrong with the graphics card.  There could be something else wrong, but the BIOS showing up means that the CPU is probably OK, but the artifacts point at the GPU rather than the rest of the system.

Comment: upload the dmp file so that we can analyze it.